# When に does not seem to denote change of place

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-で

[This answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60/particles-%E3%81%AB-vs-%E3%81%A7) explains that when used to indicate a place, で means the action is happening at that place while に indicated the verbs causes a change in place. That all makes sense until I run into some sentences where に is used but there seem to be no change of places.

> 私の掌**に**灯る誰も知らない線香花火　ー「線香花火」

> 草の上**に**地図を広げた　思い出は風の中　ー「夏の贈り物」

I'd fully expected で since 灯る and 広げる was done in that place, just like 部屋の中で灯る or 部屋の中で地図を広げる. Why the に?

Comment: The linked question has 8 answers, but none of them appear to use the word "change"? Can you explain which answer you're referring to?

Comment: The first one is a literary usage of に. The second is related to this. [How is 前に and 前で being used with 止まる and 止める respectively?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/92781/43676)

Comment: No native speaker would understand 屋の中に泣いている as "crying **into**..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私の掌**で**灯る線香花火 and 私の掌**に**灯る線香花火 describe the same scene, but the latter has a poetic sound to it. I get an image of the light emitted from the stick firework shining the palm from it. The version with で, in contrast, is more matter-of-fact and has its focus on where it is burning.

The difference between 草の上**で**地図を広げた and 草の上**に**地図を広げた is much greater. The former means you spread the map while you were on the grass as で denotes a place within the boundaries of which some action or event happens. The version with に means you spread the map **onto** the grass. This does involve a change of place as the map is now on the grass as a result of the action.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like my understanding of に and で was too limited